# How to load <iframe> after clicking on an image to improve performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Good evening, My first message here, where I read so much and did a lot of research to find a solution but without a good result. As a title, a good way to block uploads, when accessing the page, is contained within the `<iframe>` tags.

An example of code is: `<iframe> width = "560" height = "315" src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/example" frameborder = "0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>`

I have read several codes on how to enter the youtube iframe and allow the upload of external resources later, more precisely after clicking on a preview image, adapting html, csss, and javascript in sync with the youtube video id .
But I did not try this solution because the affected iframes are not just part of youtube but they come from other sources, always with the same arrangement as in the above example, and found nothing that could guide me towards the right direction.

Always hoping I'm well explained, do you have any hints on how to hide iframes load and overlap a page loading image at the click, disappear, showing the contents of the frame? Thank you. Forgive my very poor English.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Try a search on lazy loading. You also could insert the iframe itself on click.

Comment: Thank you, Axel. I did not know lazy load.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an example for YouTube and just replace the iframe source along with the other variables with your own data. Just skip the thumbnail image part. Replace the on-click event with your own event if you need to.

The technique remains the same. YouTube or not!

see this vanilla js [example](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-lazy-load-embedded-youtube-videos--cms-26743)

Make sure your video's have unique ID's. Render the HTML like this.

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($sources as $source): ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>

    <div class="video" id="video-<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <div class="divise" id="divise-<?php echo $i; ?>" data-embed="<?php echo $source; ?>">
            <div class="play-button"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. However, I can not assign the "src" attribute that contains the iframe to "embedded data". I try to explain it better. The site contains thousands of embeds with the classic <iframe> tag. How do I assign "data embed" what is "src" in the iframe?

Comment: How do you fetch the data (the source url of the iframes) ? Do you get them from a DB with PHP? then you can fetch them from the DB and render the HTML iframes with a loop. The example already has a loop in the JS so if you have multiple iframes it will initiate all iframes.

Comment: Modifying the code this way:  '<div id="video"> <?php if($player = get_post_custom_values("embed_pelicula")) { ?> <div id="divse" style="display: block;"> <div class="playimg" data-embed=<?php echo do_shortcode($player[0]); ?>> <div class="play-button"></div> 
</div> </div>' adding javascript and css styles, it works perfectly only with new videos added inserting the src. As for all the other videos, the iframe returns the error, because data-embed detects the entire <iframe> instead of just "src". How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: It basically brings me back to page 404 in the iframe instead of the video.I guess the cause is from inserting the video. Through the entire iframe. In fact, if you inspect the page, in the "data-embed" the entire iframe including the <Iframe> tag is displayed.

Comment: Just make sure the `data-embed` attribute contains the entire iframe source url as value. In the javascript remove everything around the variable where the `src` attribute gets set.

Comment: In the javascript `iframe.setAttribute( "src", this.dataset.embed );`Works correctly if I insert a new post with only the src in the field instead of the entire iframe. The problem is all the posts with the videos you have already inserted. Returns the site iframe on page 404. It's as if I should tell you to only take the "src" element in every inserted iframe. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: The only thing you need to insert is the src attribute as that is the only thing that differs from other iframes.

Comment: I followed the example you modified in the answer. But entering that loop as you wrote the page disappears. I do not know what the cause is.

Comment: Alternatively, I just have to edit every post where <iframe> is inserted, just entering the "src" attribute. This works perfectly. Unless there is a way to do it automatically without putting the site offline for thousands of changes.

Comment: you could write a script that gets all iframes from the database and put them in an array with the post ID as key and the iframe string as value like this:

`$iframes = [ 1 => '<iframe scr="http://foo.bar"></iframe>', 2 => '<iframe scr="http://baz.bar">' ];`

Extract the string in the src attribute and build an array of sources.

`$sources = [ 1 => 'http://foo.bar', 2 => 'http://baz.bar' ];`

Then use this array of sources to update the posts in the database

Comment: extract the urls from the strings in a loop like this: 

`$str = '<iframe src="http://foo.bar"></iframe>';
$s = explode('src="',$str);
$t = explode('">',$s[1]);
$url = $t[0];`